# How to ask for user consent if user leaves the EU region?

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform

I have implemented the new CMP (Consent Management Platform) for getting user consent from EU region users. And this works correctly for me without any issues.

My issue is how do I re-ask for the consent or reset the consent if the user moves out of the EU region.

Situation is my user resides in a NON EU region, travels to EU region for a business or assignment for a short period and is then back home in the NON EU region.

When in EU region user confirms to NO ads but once he is back those settings continue as it is since `ConsentStatus = OBTAINED` and he continues to see NO ads.

How do I reset the consent based on his location ?

My app does not need location and so Google will reject my app even if I ask for coarse location permissions.

I can reset consent unconditionally (`consentInformation.reset();`)every time the user uses my app but then that would amount to asking for consent every time he/she uses my app which is not a good user experience.

Any workarounds for this situation ?